# Menu bar changing position from computer to computer

Tags: html, css, menu, positioning

I'm having an issue with my main menu bar on my website. Just to be clear i am referring to the menu bar on my website that has links such as "About" and "home". I want this menu bar to be in the centre (which it is on my computer which has a 15" screen). However when i look at my website on other computers some which have a a bigger screen, the menu bar is significantly off centre to the right or left and it looks a bit rubbish. How can i standardise the position of my menu bar so it is in the centre regardless of what internet browser or different screen size is being used?

Thanks

Ben

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutme.css">
        <title>It's all about me!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        <header>
            <div class="grow">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="like.html">What I love</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <h1>About Me</h1>
        <img src="ben.jpg" id="ben">
        <h2>The Beginning:</h2>
        <div id="beginning">
            <p>I absolutely love coding ever since I was young. I started finding the fascination with it when I started playing a game called "runescape". When I started playing in 2007, the "botting" community started to grow massively. As a full time gamer, I found this out within that community. During my subscription with the botting client "powerbot", I started to learn JAVA and played around with other people's code. Even though I never became an expert within that language, I managed to design simple scripts which allowed my character to level up on basic skills whilst I was alseep! I loved the problem solving! I absolutely loved the community and how everyone worked as a team. However, I soon grew out of it after Runescape's anti-botting software got too advanced and I decided to play normally!
        </div>
        <h3>SEO and Web Developing:</h3>
        <div id="seo">
            <p>After finishing my education, I decided not to study a degree as there wasn't anything that I felt suited me at that time. I preferred to take on more of an entrepreneurial career. I decided to join my friend's business "GR Syndicate". Over that following years, I learnt SEO and Web developing. The Web Developing purely consisted of only coding with HTML and CSS and the websites we created were used to sell cosmetic products off. During that time, I built upon my SEO skills and developed them to rank high in Google's SERPS. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <h4>The Present</h4>
        <div id="present">
            <p>After working in GR Syndicate and in customer service, coding was missing from my life. This is when I decided to practice my code by building a website about one of my other passions, dogs. This gave me the opportunity to really understand CSS3 and HTML5. Even though I find CSS3 hard as there are a lot of interactive elements involved, it is my favorite part of CSS. I absolutely love the animations I see on "CSS Deck" being created the whole time. This gave me the motivation to add a couple of CSS3 elements in this website, and in my other website, such as a hero that consisted of changing pictures. After learning about more code from producing the dog website, I realised how much I loved doing it. This is when I started looking at courses, and found General Assembly. I went to the open day and I was very impressed, and I hope you are too with this website!                    </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

  ------------------------CSS in another file------------------------

body {
    background-image: url(puppy.jpg);
}



h1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}



#content
    { font-family:'lobster', cursive;
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      font-size: 23px;
      top: 80px;
      left: 25px;

}
.grow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 550px;
    top: 700px;
}


a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dcf3ff;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;

}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;

}

.grow {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

#box {
    width: 485px;
    height: 500px;

}
```

Comment: Use a CSS reset for starters

Comment: All your elements are absolute, is there a reason for this other than centring them? You can use `position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` to centre your items on your page. This will prevent the elements on your page from overlapping everywhere. Also, you shouldn't be changing all the html tags directly in css like you have. You should only be changing things like font properties which wouldn't change throughout your document. Create classes and id's instead and change your element's css via its class or id. This will clean up your code and will prevent undesired behaviour

Comment: To add to my previous comment, when I say you should add classes, add them to either the elements themselves like `<li class='menuItem'>` and use `.menuItem{...}` in your css or surround the items with a div (with id or class) and access that instead like `<div class='menuItems'><ul><li>...</li>...</ul></div>`, and in your css `.menuItems>ul>li{...}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove position absolute from your element it is not nessesary to give always `position:absolute` to make a div center.

Then change the style as follows

```
#content {
    font-family:'lobster', cursive;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/3rqyk9fm/)

**UPDATED**

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
ul li a{
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/3rqyk9fm/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. If I get rid of the 'absolute' the menu appears at the top more lengthened. Was that intentional as I would like it to be centered-bottom. Thanks.

Comment: I dont get the exact requirement will you more specific

Comment: Your css is full of mess try restarting from scratch

Comment: I would like the menu to appear at the center-bottom of that page. The reason I used absolute to position it was so I could define where I wanted it to go, at the center-bottom. However, on other computers it is not centered at the bottom. It is either to the left or right, depending on the size of the computer screen. It changes and I don't know why.

Comment: Thats the case why dont you use your nav in footer

Comment: Do you want your menu to be visible at all times or just when people scroll to the base of your page?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want if you work out the right values for the positioning of your bar on the screen, however, it'd be difficult to mantain that positioning on different screen geometries. If you really want to position an element at the center-bottom of the screen, then this may help you ([example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/f60ypxvt/)):

HTML:

```
<nav id="Navbar">
    <ul id="Buttonbar">
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link #2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#Navbar {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
}

#Buttonbar {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    background: grey;
}

#Buttonbar>li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Notice that I've used the `nav` element as my holder, giving it a 100% width so it adjusts to any screen/window geometry and then I gave my `ul` an absolute size (and the background too) so it is always in the middle. Then I just set my `nav` to be at the botton, holding everything there. Hint: if you want the navbar to *always* be in the bottom, you can also use the `fixed` positioning attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've edited your website to how I believe you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/3rqyk9fm/2/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
         <h1>About Me</h1>


<h2>The Beginning:</h2>

        <div id="beginning">
            <p>I absolutely love coding ever since I was young. I started finding the fascination with it when I started playing a game called "runescape". When I started playing in 2007, the "botting" community started to grow massively. As a full time gamer, I found this out within that community. During my subscription with the botting client "powerbot", I started to learn JAVA and played around with other people's code. Even though I never became an expert within that language, I managed to design simple scripts which allowed my character to level up on basic skills whilst I was alseep! I loved the problem solving! I absolutely loved the community and how everyone worked as a team. However, I soon grew out of it after Runescape's anti-botting software got too advanced and I decided to play normally!</p>
        </div>

<h3>SEO and Web Developing:</h3>

        <div id="seo">
            <p>After finishing my education, I decided not to study a degree as there wasn't anything that I felt suited me at that time. I preferred to take on more of an entrepreneurial career. I decided to join my friend's business "GR Syndicate". Over that following years, I learnt SEO and Web developing. The Web Developing purely consisted of only coding with HTML and CSS and the websites we created were used to sell cosmetic products off. During that time, I built upon my SEO skills and developed them to rank high in Google's SERPS.</p>
        </div>

<h4>The Present</h4>

        <div id="present">
            <p>After working in GR Syndicate and in customer service, coding was missing from my life. This is when I decided to practice my code by building a website about one of my other passions, dogs. This gave me the opportunity to really understand CSS3 and HTML5. Even though I find CSS3 hard as there are a lot of interactive elements involved, it is my favorite part of CSS. I absolutely love the animations I see on "CSS Deck" being created the whole time. This gave me the motivation to add a couple of CSS3 elements in this website, and in my other website, such as a hero that consisted of changing pictures. After learning about more code from producing the dog website, I realised how much I loved doing it. This is when I started looking at courses, and found General Assembly. I went to the open day and I was very impressed, and I hope you are too with this website!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainMenu">
        <div class="grow">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="like.html">What I love</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
    color:black;
    min-width:500px;
}
#content {
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
#content>h1 {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#mainMenu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dcf3ff;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}
#mainMenu ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
#mainMenu {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:500px;
}
#mainMenu>.grow {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.grow {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.7s;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.grow:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```